What word does Aristotle use to mean logic (translated) in Metaphysics, 1005b?
My copy of the WD Ross translation of Metaphysics includes the paragraph below in 005al9-1005b8.
And the attempts of some who discuss the terms on which truth should be accepted, are due to a want of training in logic; for they should know these things already when they come to a special study, and not be inquiring into them while they are pursuing it-Evidently then the philosopher, who is studying the nature of all substance, must inquire also into the principles of deduction.
I cannot read or speak Greek, but I know that logos is spelled λόγος, and I do not see λόγος in that section of a Greek edition. What Greek word, then, did Ross translate as logic?

Maybe there's a Greek phrase "principles of deuction", which is synonymous with logic.

Because logos is not "logic".

Many philosophers and logicians have used logos to mean logic including the Stoics and NeoPlatonists

A's treatises have been translTed in Latin as Prior and Posterior Analytics.

The word is ἀναλυτικῶν which might be translated slightly more broadly as analytical study.

Google translates ἀναλυτικῶν as "analysts", as in δι᾽ ἀπαιδευσίαν [4] τῶν ἀναλυτικῶν, "due to illiteracy [4] of the analysts". Metaphysics 1005b

@ChrisDegnen Google is using modern Greek. Google does not feature an option to translate Attic Greek, which is quite different. ἀναλυτικῶν is literally 'analytics' but it is better translated as analytical study or logical analysis.

How does that work in the context of δι᾽ ἀπαιδευσίαν [4] τῶν ἀναλυτικῶν ? because it looks like Aristotle is using as "illiteracy of the analysts"

@ChrisDegnen A literal translation is: "There is a kind of wisdom in physics, but it is not the first. Some of those who discuss how one should accept the truth do so out of ignorance of analytics: for it is necessary to approach these matters with prior knowledge rather than seeking while listening."

Thanks very much

Re. WD Ross's translation

And the attempts of some who discuss the terms on which truth should
be accepted, are due to a want of training in logic

The Greek at 1005b

ὅσα δ᾽ ἐγχειροῦσι τῶν λεγόντων τινὲς περὶ τῆς ἀληθείας ὃν τρόπον δεῖ
ἀποδέχεσθαι, δι᾽ ἀπαιδευσίαν [4] τῶν ἀναλυτικῶν τοῦτο δρῶσιν

Translation by Google does not mention 'logic', (just 'analysts', ἀναλυτικῶν).

As for the operations of those who tell some about the truth, in
whatever way they see fit, they do so because of the illiteracy [4] of
the analysts

Although the translation at Perseus adds it in

As for the attempts of some of those who discuss how the truth should
be received, they are due to lack of training in logic


Where reasoning is specifically mentioned, i.e. WD Ross's translation

Evidently then the philosopher, who is studying the nature of all
substance, must inquire also into the principles of deduction.

The Greek at 1005b has

ὅτι μὲν οὖν τοῦ φιλοσόφου, καὶ τοῦ περὶ πάσης τῆς οὐσίας θεωροῦντος ᾗ
πέφυκεν, καὶ περὶ τῶν συλλογιστικῶν ἀρχῶν ἐστὶν ἐπισκέψασθαι,
δῆλον: προσήκει δὲ τὸν μάλιστα γνωρίζοντα περὶ ἕκαστον γένος ἔχειν
λέγειν τὰς βεβαιοτάτας ἀρχὰς [10]

συλλογιστικῶν ἀρχῶν (syllogistikón archón) translates as reasoning principles.
Google translate gives

for if the philosopher's opinion, and the one who is considered to
have fallen away from everything about essence, and about the
syllogistic principles, he is deluded: it belongs to him who in fact
knows about each genus, who has said the most certain principles [10]

And Perseus provides a more natural translation

Clearly then it is the function of the philosopher, i.e. the student
of the whole of reality in its essential nature, to investigate also
the principles of syllogistic reasoning.


For completeness, here is how Google translates the whole passage, WD Ross version first

And the attempts of some who discuss the terms on which truth should
be accepted, are due to a want of training in logic; for they should
know these things already when they come to a special study, and not
be inquiring into them while they are pursuing it-Evidently then the
philosopher, who is studying the nature of all substance, must inquire
also into the principles of deduction.


As for the
operations of those who tell some about the truth, in whatever way
they see fit, they do so because of the illiteracy [4] of the
analysts: for see about these [5] they are in charge, but they ask
without hearing.
for if the philosopher's opinion, and the one who is considered to
have fallen away from everything about essence, and about the
syllogistic principles, he is deluded: it belongs to him who in fact
knows about each genus, who has said the most certain principles [10]

Obviously machine translation lacks nuance, but it does provide a literal attempt.
